# How to make write an initial value to a client side text input?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

How do I set an initial value for a client side text input? It has to be client side because it needs to be assigned an initial value, edited by the user, and then sent back to the server. I have both input of type text and a textarea that need to implement this behaviour.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASP.NET Razor you maybe do as the following:
This creates a div-container with a red border and a textbox inside it and
a button called "submit".

```
 <div style="border:1px solid red">
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionResult method", "controller"))
{
<p>Name:</p>
{
if (Session["Name"] == null) 
{
Session["Name"] = string.Empty;
}
@Html.TextBox("name", Session["Name"].ToString());
}
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" />
}
</div>
```

Of course you can use instead of Session["key"] other types.
If you don't use Razor the syntax is sligh different. Then it's <%= instead of @.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML below show you how to set an initial value on a input of type text and a text area:

```
<input type="text" value="Initial Value" id="txtName" />
<textarea cols="5" rows="10">Initial Value</textarea>
```